# Unable to load a list of classes using the pickle function in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, persistence, pickle

I have a script I've written that stores class instances of expenses and income in lists.

When first starting the module, I use a try/except block to check for a pickled file:

```
try:
        #list definitions
        expenselist = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
        incomelist = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
except:
        print ("Generating new lists.")
        #list definitions
        expenselist = []
        incomelist = []
```

This works as intended when run in IDLE:
[test-slide-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx626.jpg)

The program prints the debug message about generating new lists and prints the blank lists. It then prompts the user for input to create a class instance that is appended to the empty lists.

```
enterValue = str(input("Hi, press 1 to enter income and 2 to expense"))

    try:
        if enterValue == '1':
            addIncome ()
            #printRev()#debug to print class
        elif enterValue == '2':
            addExpense ()
            #printExp() #debug to print class
        else:
            raise ValueError 
    except ValueError:
        print ("Incorrect Value.")
```

This produces this result in IDLE:
[test-slide-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJaUi.jpg)

It is then pickled using:

```
#pickle expenselist
pickle.dump(expenselist,open(filename,'wb'))

#pickle incomelist
pickle.dump(incomelist,open(filename,'wb'))
```

The pickled data is stored here:
[file_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imct9.jpg)

When I open this file using Notepad++, I get this:

€]q .

So I know it stored something.

Everything until now has gone according to design, but when I run the script again, I get:
[test-slide-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfxEc.jpg)

My debugging message about generating new lists didn't print, so I know it detected and tried to load the file, but it printed blank lists instead of the data I had stored in the list during the previous session.

I've tried for weeks now to figure out what was going on. I originally thought it was saving the location of the class instance and not the instance itself, but it should print the address of the instance if that were the case. Instead I'm getting blank lists.

My questions are: 1, is it generating new lists regardless of loading the pickle and how do I stop it? and 2, if that isn't the problem, what is?

I'm about 50% self taught and I've exhausted the resources I know of. I've had two programmers take a look at the code, but neither are Python experts. So this is the only thing I haven't tried.

Comment: I believe that your dumping of `incomelist` will overwrite your previously dumped `expenselist` since you are re-opening the same file with `w` flag, which, according to the documentation will: `open for writing, truncating the file first`. Similarly, your `load` statements reopen the same file, thus resetting the file to the beginning again.

Comment: So I need to store the lists in two different files?

Comment: No, just open the file once, as in the answer provided by @progmatico.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is very simple to use. I recommend using a with statement and like in the comment by @John Anderson, it looks like you are overwriting a file.

Usage example:

```
import pickle

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
with open("pickle1.dat", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
    pickle.dump(b, f)

c = None
d = None
with open("pickle1.dat", 'rb') as f:
    c = pickle.load(f)
    d = pickle.load(f)

print(c)
print(d)
```

Outputs

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```